# LinkedIn - Getting Access Token Error invalid_redirect_uri

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

has anyone succeeded in connecting to Linkedin API here?
I followed the instructions on the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin%2Fmarketing%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-2022-11&tabs=HTTPS1) but failed to retrieve the Authorization Code.
Here's the result of my POST request to get the `access_token`

[image]

```
{
    "error": "invalid_redirect_uri",
    "error_description": "Unable to retrieve access token: appid/redirect uri/code verifier does not match authorization code. Or authorization code expired. Or external member binding exists"
}
```

I'm using the https//airbyte.io as a redirect_uri
My GET get request to obtain the authorization token is the following:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=78oy2gu644mxz2&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fairbyte.io&scope=r_ads,r_ads_reporting,r_organization_social
```

I followed a couple advices in the different thread in SO

- double checked my `client_id` and `client_secret`
- encoded the URI in GET request
- added scope parameters to the `redirect_url` at the POST request
- Tested the request with the `code` within 20 seconds window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. Ensure your redirect URI is also defined within your app's configuration as an allowed redirect URI. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin%2Fmarketing%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-2022-11&tabs=HTTPS1#step-1-configure-your-application. The documentation specifies a certain URL to use when testing with Postman.
2. In your authorization call, your scopes are comma-delimited. They should be space-delimited and URL-encoded. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin%2Fmarketing%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-2022-11&tabs=HTTPS1#step-2-request-an-authorization-code.

Comment: Thanks, mate! The Postman guide in the official doc helped.